# Find files in a directory for two days i.e today's and Yesterday

Tags: command-line

I need a command or shell script to find files within a folder for today and yesterday in Linux.

#### Example

If I run the command today it should give me the list of files created today and also yesterday.

I tried the following commands but didn't get the expected output:

```
find . -type f -mtime +2 -prune -o -mtime +1 -exec ls -ltr {} \;
```

It is giving me only one file for today and some of yesterday and the day before yesterday.

Comment: When you say "created", do you really mean created, or does modified do the job you want?

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `find`:

```
find . -daystart -type f -mtime -2 -mtime +-1 -ls
```

Would give you the files last modified between yesterday 00:00:00 and today 23:59:59.999999999. It could give you wrong results around the switch from/to summer time (in timezones that have winter/summer time) as it counts the number of 24 hours unit from the start of today and around the switch to/from summer time, there is one 23 or 25 hour long day.

You could also do (still with GNU `find`):

```
find . -type f -newermt yesterday ! -newermt tomorrow -ls
```

But that would give files modified at exactly 00:00:00.000000000 tomorrow, and not the one modified at that time yesterday. It's terribly unlikely for a file to have been last modified in that very nanosecond, but that could happen for files whose modification time has been set arbitrarily with `touch` for instance or on filesystems that don't have sub-second time granularity.

With `zsh`:

```
autoload age # best in ~/.zshrc
ls -lrtd -- *(D.e:'age yesterday tomorrow':)
```

Or recursively  like with `find`:

```
ls -lrtd -- **/*(D.e:'age yesterday tomorrow':)
```

(same note about boundaries as for `find -newermt` above).

---

As to why you didn't get the right result with:

```
find . -type f -mtime +2 -prune -o -mtime +1 -exec ls -ltr {} \;
```

First note that `-a` (implied when omitted) has precedence over `-o`, so the above is actually:

```
find . \( -type f -a -mtime +2 -a -prune \) -o \
  \( -mtime +1 -a -exec ls -ltr {} \; \)
```

So the `-type f` only applies in the fist group.

`-mtime +2` selects files whose age rounded up to the next day (24 hour) unit is strictly greater than 2, that is files that have been last modified more than 48 hours ago (compared to the current date), and `-mtime +1` files that have been last modified more than 24 hours ago.

You want the age compared to the start of the day (hence the (GNU specific) `-daystart`).

Also note that with `-exec ls -lrt {} \;`, you're running one `ls` per file, so the `-rt` option to sort the files is useless has `ls` has only one file to sort. You could use `-exec ls -lrt {} +` instead, but even then, if the list of files is big, `ls` may be called several times.

Comment: This command doesn't provide the right output :-(
Suppose my directory contains :-


Jul 15 00:01 a.log-20160716.gz
Jul 16 17:26 b.log
Jul 17 17:26 c.zip.log
Jul 17 17:27 d.log
Jul 17 21:49 e.log'.'2016-07-16
Jul 18 06:09 f.log

The output of the command should be :-

Jul 17 17:26 c.zip.log
Jul 17 17:27 d.log
Jul 17 21:49 e.log'.'2016-07-16
Jul 18 06:09 f.log

Comment: @ArpitGupta, that's what it (both) gives me? What does it give you? Is it because you want the list sorted by date? Then see my edit.

Comment: The below command works for me :-

find . -type f -newermt yesterday ! -newermt tomorrow -ls >New.text

However I am getting the day and timestamp in the output file New.text.

I only want the file name i.e c.zip.log and so on.

Also I am getting ./ in the file name like ./c.zip.log

Any suggestion ?

Comment: @ArpitGupta, then use `-print` instead of `-ls`. `-ls` is a shorter (and more efficient) version of your `-exec ls -lrt {} \;`. To avoid the `./`, with GNU `find`, replace `-print` with `-printf '%P\n'`. Replace `\n` with `\0` to be able to pass the output to `xargs -r0` if need be.

Comment: Shazelas :

I am getting the file names now but there is a problem.
I am getting output as :-

./c.zip.log
./d.log
./e.log
./f.log

I don't know from where its taking in the command but I don't want this "./" before file name.

Any help please ?

Comment: @ArpitGupta, see my previous comment. Note that having `./` is fine. You asked to search in `.`, so the paths are reported in there. Prepending `./` to relative file paths is often a good idea as it avoids problems with filenames that start with `-` (or sometimes + or blanks).